# 2.9- How do you keyframe an object's render visibility?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, timeline, visibility

I want my object to be visible until frame 50 then have its render visibility turned off. how can I do this? eevee

Comment: Is making the object transparent after frame 50 an option?

Comment: yea but I'm gonna do it a lot so if its gonna be a hassle to do every time then i might need an better method

Comment: For the object's material, if you add a Value Node, you can click the value field and enter `#frame` as a value. This will make the value match the value of the frame at any given point. Use this node, plugged in to a Math Node, set to `greater than` and set the value to 50. Mix your existing material output with a Transparent Shader, (using a Mix Shader) and use the Value/Math Node setup as the mix factor (you may need to invert it first). I'm sorry I can't post an image of the setup, but my GPU died this morning and I can't even open blender without it.

Comment: hey im sorry to hear that about your GPU and thanks your suggestion really helped me alot.

Comment: Hey no problem. Glad you could figure it out from that mess of instructions. And yeah, we'll say a prayer for my GPU - it's rendered it's final scene....

Comment: Blunder's answer seems pretty functional as well, you should also give that a try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the answer to this question in this tutorial [Blender 2.83 : Grab & Release Weapons (In 60 Seconds!!!) by Royal Skies LLC](https://youtu.be/Mf1Sh_nPSas) a while ago.

You can keyframe the object's visibility in the `Object Properties`, section `Visibility`. There are 2 checkboxes to control it: Show in `Renders` and ... `Viewports`.

Comment: thanks! this is just what i was looking for