# How not to render objects when they are out of the frame?

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects

I understand i want too much,
but is it possible to disable object when it's not in the frame.
It's just for rendering time reduce.
I see that it's unable to set keyframe on the render icon, but may be there is another way to do it?
Thank for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

to switch visibility during rendering/animation just hit I when your cursor hovers over the little camera icon to add a keyframe. Then move the timeline cursor to another frame and tap on the little camera icon to toggle it and hove over it again and tap I again -> ready.

The other "place" where you can set the keyframe is here: (it has the same effect): (Renders)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So it works even without the keyframe points... is
it really useful, do you think? Will this help speed up the renderers?

Comment: Everything you don‘t render which is in camera view will speed up your render. If it isn‘t in the camera view it will have no effect.

Comment: So you mean, there is no need to hide all objects? )

Answer (score 1):

In the Outliner (window usually at upper right of workspace), click on the small funnel looking button to the right. In there, you'll see a series of icons that you can use to toggle visibility.

The little camera is for rendering. If you click on that little camera icon next to the object you don't want to render and it goes dark, the object will not be rendered.

In answer to your comment, Blender doesn't render anything that's not in the camera view, so it's only taking up render power once it enters the frame.

Comment: I know that. ))) But is it possible to switch visibility during rendering? 
You know, like keyframes for scale/rotation or location...

Comment: Yes, you can keyframe the visibility: [2.9- How do you keyframe an object's render visibility?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/196888/107598)

Comment: it doesn't render but in Cycles the object will be taken into account as it influences on the indirect lighting